# Load removed div element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two following div elements:

```
<div class='staticMap'></div>
<div class='geolocation-common-map'></div>
```

The div called *'geolocation-common-map'* is removed using jQuery when the page is loaded. I would like to know how can I load this div again after the div *'staticMap'* is clicked. So far I have following jQuery, but I need to replace *.show()* function.

```
$('.geolocation-common-map').remove();
$('.staticMap').on("click", function(event) {
   $('.geolocation-common-map').show();
   $('.staticMap').remove();
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is your issue? The code looks fine to me. Just don't remove .geolocation-common-map but hide it as you do in the code snippet.

Comment: @mplungjan I dont want the div to even load to HTML, so show/hide is not what I am looking for.

Comment: So where is your code to load .geolocation-common-map?

Comment: why don't you use hide() instead of remove() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [**detach documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/detach/):

> The `.detach()` method is the same as `.remove()`, except that `.detach()` keeps all `jQuery` data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

You can use it as follow:

```js
var dv_geolocation_common_map = $( ".geolocation-common-map" ).detach();
var dv_staticMap = $('.staticMap');

$('.staticMap').on("click", function(event) {
  dv_geolocation_common_map.insertAfter(dv_staticMap)
   dv_staticMap.detach();
   event.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
.staticMap{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:green;
}
.geolocation-common-map{
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='staticMap'></div>
<div class='geolocation-common-map'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of remove(), try toggle():

```
<div class='staticMap'></div>
<div class='geolocation-common-map'></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.geolocation-common-map').hide();
  $('.staticMap').on("click", function (event) {
    $('.geolocation-common-map').toggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Try jQuery Online</title>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#geolocation').hide();
    $("#staticMap").click(function(){
       $('#geolocation').show();
    });
    
   
});

</script>
<style>
.selected { 
    color:red; 
}
.highlight { 
    background:yellow; 
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="staticMap" class='staticMap selected'>Static Map</div>
<div id="geolocation" class='geolocation-common-map highlight'>Geolocation Map</div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Adding id to your your static div or changing the id to class in jquery will do your work.you are using staticMap as id but it is not defined in div.